# How do I convert these embedded elements into attributes of the parent element?

Tags: c#, xslt, serialization, xsd

I have a large XSD, with elements that look like this:

```
<xs:element name="ProgramName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>PN</xs:documentation> 
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="TestItem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>TA</xs:documentation> 
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

I would like to collapse the `<documentation>` element into an attribute of the grandparent element, like this:

```
<xs:element name="ProgramName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" code="PN">
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="TestItem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" code="TA">
</xs:element>
```

How could this be done with XSLT?  Alternatively, is there a better (read: simpler) way to do it than XSLT?

The resulting XSD will be used with `XSD.EXE` to create a C# class, for serialization and deserialization purposes.  The original XSD cannot be used this way, because `XSD.EXE` drops all of the annotation elements, so the information contained in those annotations is lost.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[xs:annotation]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="code"><xsl:value-of select="xs:annotation/xs:documentation"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xs:annotation"/>      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I just have to figure out how to execute it against the original XSD. :P  As you might have guessed, I have zero experience with XSLT, although I do know what it's purpose is.  I bow to the great XSLT gurus who are much more enlightened than I.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm definitely no guru, but I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This Just another answer :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[local-name()='element']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[local-name()!='annotation']"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="node()[local-name()='annotation']/node()[local-name()='documentation']">
        <xsl:attribute name="code">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Indeed a very good thought of using XSLT for rearranging nodes rather than doing it manually :) I always make use of XSLT .. 

We can even use it to generate sample XMLs from XSD .. if XSD is with bearable size :)

Comment: I would suggest you try your XSLT against one XSD which has some global types as well; a simple one, such as the one posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043414/how-to-define-a-specific-number-in-xsd) on SO. You'll see that yours doesn't work, at least compared with @DevNull's... I'll let you figure out why... then maybe you can update your post.

Comment: @PetruGardea, It works for the OPs question .. If element has complex type defined within, then my code doesn't work I know that  .. that is because I am ignoring all the ELEMENT nodes within `<xs:element/>`.. instead if they define complextype else where and use it as type for Element it should work.

Comment: @PetruGardea, I will update my answer rightaway .. to make it work for example you have mentioned.

Comment: is the downvoter having enough courtesy to let me know the reason for downvoting??