# How to define a specific number in xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

i am working on an xsd-specification (for a simple game ;) ) which has that specification:

I have an Elem `players` with an attribute `number`, which indicates the number of the players(a num between `1 and 4`). As childelems, it contains elems of zero to four `screenname` elements. These elements have player screenname text content and attribute, which indicates the end of the game number (a number between `1 and 4`).

My big problems are the screenname and the Intervall in a typ in xsd?
So how to do that?

greetings and thx in advance

Comment: Probably a good idea to add an XML sample of what you want. I'm hungover.

Comment: I agree with @Nick, chances of getting better answers, faster, are higher when you post a sample XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you're describing:

```
<players number="2">
    <screenname endofgame="3">player screenname text content</screenname>
</players>
```

This would be an automatically generated XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="players">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="screenname">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
              <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="endofgame" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required" />
              </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="number" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This would be one with additional constraints, as described: `a num between 1 and 4` and  `zero to four screenname elements`. By looking at before/after, you should understand which one is which.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="players">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="screenname" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
              <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="endofgame" type="Int1to4" use="required" />
              </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="number" type="Int1to4" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:simpleType name="Int1to4">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
      <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
      <xsd:maxInclusive value="4"/>
    </xsd:restriction>  
  </xsd:simpleType> 
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify the amount of recurrence of an element you need to use the minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes.